# Why I am getting 'jira (Interface: soap) Bug id' if I am integrating with REST

Tags: testlink, jira

[image]Why I am getting 'jira (Interface: soap) Bug id' if I am integrating with REST?

If I am integrating with REST then I should get the message as 'jira (Interface: rest) Bug id'

I am using below codes for Integration

JIRA LOGIN NAME

JIRA PASSWORD

https//testlink.alssian.net

https://testlink.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/

JIRA PROJECT KEY

JIRA ISSUE TYPE

Comment: Can you please describe a bit detail about the issue being faced by you. I am not able to get your question.

Comment: You may get a better response from Stack Overflow - this is more of a programming question than a testing question.

Comment: did you make sure you selected jira rest instead of jira soap?

Comment: Yes I selected 'Jira Rest' and Once after execution of test cases when I am linking executed test cases with Jira then I am getting user message 'Jira (Interface: soap) Bug id' to attach there. So I am getting confuse that if I have used Jira Rest then why 'Jira (Interface: soap) Bug id' is asking there. I think 'Jira (Interface: rest) Bug id' should be asked there.

Comment: This looks like their message, so it may not be related to a "soap" interface, but might be a legacy message that wasn't updated to REST.  You need to ask Atlasian people on that one though as it's their message specifically.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a product specific message and unrelated to Software Quality Assurance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a product specific message and unrelated to Software Quality Assurance